# Can't get PageUp/PageDown KeyEvent

Tags: android, keyevent

I used the standard project template with `Fragment` with the toolbar, floating action button and menu. And I want to get `PageUp/PageDown KeyEvent` from MainActivity, but `onKeyUp/onKeyDown/dispatchKeyEvent` can't get those `KeyEvents`. Most other `KeyEvents` work fine but `PageUp/PageDown` don't. Are they blocked? How to detect them?

I suspect that it's blocked by some other views, so I removed the menu, toolbar, floating action button and the text view inside fragment but still, it didn't work.

```
fragment_main.xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("####", "Key pressed " + keyCode);
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("####", "Key dispatch " + event);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I used an emulator to test this, when I press the ArrowUp key on my keyboard I get this:

```
I/####: Key dispatch KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, scanCode=103, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=92263282, downTime=92263282, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
I/####: Key dispatch KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, scanCode=103, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=92263434, downTime=92263282, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
I/####: Key pressed 19
```

But when I pressed `PageUp/PageDown` nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's the emulator problem. I didn't try all the emulators but the emulators I used are from Android Studio. After I connected to a real blue tooth keyboard the program can get the KEYCODE_PAGE_UP and KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN events correctly!
So my suggestions is if you want to test keyboard/mouse don't rely on the emulators!